# Counting query from more than two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables :

Name : Table_inventory

| id | device_type | location | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

Name : Table_device_type

| id | device_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC |
| 2 | Laptop |
| 3 | Smartphone |
| 4 | Telephone |

Name : Table_location

| id | device_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Store |
| 2 | Sales |
| 3 | Workshop |

Name : Table_status

| id | device_sts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Broken |
| 2 | In Use |
| 3 | Disposed |

The desired outlook :
first

```
No Location    Total inventory   PC    Laptop     Smartphone    Telephone
1  Store       3                 1     0          1            1
2  Sales       3                 0     2          1            0
3  Workshop    3                 2     0          0            1
```

second

```
No Location    PC    Broken    In Use     Disposed
1  Store       1     0          1            0
2  Sales       0     0          0            0
3  Workshop    2     1          1            0
```

Please advise what is the SQL command to be executed.

Comment: What's the name of your database engine? SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, etc.

Comment: Same comments as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648467/query-combining-more-than-2-tables-and-counts?noredirect=1#comment133459201_75648467 apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e13BD2bKiHi3TC6Z6ByjYd/1):

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY L.location) AS No
      ,L.location
      ,COUNT(*) AS Total
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN D.device_type = 'PC' THEN 1 END), 0) AS PC
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN D.device_type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 END), 0) AS Laptop
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN D.device_type = 'Smartphone' THEN 1 END), 0) AS Smartphone
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN D.device_type = 'Telephone' THEN 1 END), 0) AS Telephone
FROM Table_inventory I
INNER JOIN Table_device_type D
    ON I.device_type = D.id
INNER JOIN Table_location L
    ON I.location = L.id
GROUP BY L.location
```

[image]

and the second part will be something similuar:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY L.location) AS No
      ,L.location
      ,COUNT(*) AS Total
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN S.device_sts = 'Broken' THEN 1 END), 0) AS Broken
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN S.device_sts = 'In Use' THEN 1 END), 0) AS InUse
      ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN S.device_sts = 'Disposed' THEN 1 END), 0) AS Disposed
FROM Table_inventory I
INNER JOIN Table_status S
    ON I.status = S.id
INNER JOIN Table_location L
    ON I.location = L.id
GROUP BY L.location
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. it perfectly works